# Cannot List ALL events for a given day using GCSA

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, gcsa

Firstly, new to Python but have 32 years of experience in mainframe programming in z/OS REXX. Surprisingly both are very similar and the learning curve for the basics was small. Having said that the issue I am having is with the [GCSA](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api) package/library (not up on terminology). Here's the code in question ...

```py
from gcsa.google_calendar import GoogleCalendar
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta


calendar = GoogleCalendar('******************************@group.calendar.google.com')

start_date = date.today() - timedelta(days = 1)
start_date = str(start_date) + " 00:00:01"

end_date = date.today()
end_date = str(end_date) + " 23:59:59"

calendar.get_events(start_date, end_date)

for event in calendar:
    print(event)
```

The issue is the above only returns Events that are pending. Everything else is missing. The requirement is to list ALL events from yesterday at midnight to today at midnight. At this point not sure if it's something within the calendar settings or the above code. Note: passing no parameters to (`calendar.get_events()`) gives the same result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your start date?   Why not use events.list.  are you sure you are using the official python client library?

Comment: Thanks. Start date is always the previous day to the end of the current day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of the library :)

You are almost there. Iterating over the `calendar` as you do, will go through events from today until the same date next year.

You need to iterate over the result of `calendar.get_events(start_date, end_date)`:

```
for event in calendar.get_events(start_date, end_date):
    print(event)
```

or you can use:

```
for event in calendar[start_date:end_date]:
    print(event)
```

But your `start_date` and `end_date` are strings, they need to be `date`/`datetime` objects. I suggest you use @user19077881 's suggestion to combine the date and time.

Please, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Worked! I know the rules state not to thank people in comments but I don't know how else to personally thank you. I appreciate your response and the hard work you put into GCSA. Happy holidays.

Comment: Great, glad it worked! And happy to know that people use the library :)

Answer (score 1):

get_events takes Python datetime objects as parameters; you are creating string objects to represent your chosen dates and times. See code below to construct (and also in case useful display using print) datetime objects. These can then be used as arguments in calling the calendar function.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

start_date = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.min.time())
start_date = start_date + timedelta(days= -1, minutes = 1)
end_date = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.min.time())
end_date = end_date + timedelta(hours = 23, minutes = 59, seconds = 50)

print(datetime.strftime(start_date, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print(datetime.strftime(end_date, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

which produces (for today)

```
22-12-20 00:01:00
22-12-21 23:59:50
```

Comment: Thank you so much or the quick reposnse. I made the suggested updates and nothing has changed. I'm still only getting the pending/future events. Everything scheduled yesterday and today up till this time are not showing up.

Comment: It's worth checking the API docs for the various functions. I don't have the Calendar credentials available to completely run your code.  The docs say `start_date and end_date can be date or datetime objects.` so I hope getting that sorted helps.